# Django test with pgcrypto failing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm using a PostgreSQL database for my Django app with pgcryto extension installed. On the production server I manually create a user and then run `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;` in order to install the extension.

However when I run `./manage.py test` it fails because my models are using the `EncryptedTextField` field from `pgcrypto_expressions`, the test database that's automatically created does not have the extension installed naturally (since it needs to be enabled explicitly for every database created). How can I 'inject' code / commands between the time Django sets up my test database and begins migrations?

Or rather, how can I enable this extension globally in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You can create a migration that installs the extension - see the example [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#creating-extension-using-migrations).

Comment: @Alasdair great, exactly what I need.. I've had a quick look but since I'm still a noob, where do I put this code? Any file and it'll pick it up? Do I need to insert it into the 001_... migration file (but then that gets overwritten every time)

Comment: I don't understand why it is getting overwritten. It can go in the migration file for any app you like. Ideally, add it as the `0001_initial` migration for an app. As long as any migrations that use `EncryptedTextField` have this migration as a [dependency](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#dependencies) , it should work.

Comment: I suppose it's in fact 'deleting' the initial model and re-creating it (as we've got build-scripts running on our prototype that clean and re-init the db every time they run, as the model changes quite often during development). Okay I'll think about this a bit more :) Thanks!

Comment: I've just created a new dummy app with a custom migration that installs a pgcrypto extension (I've made sure the app is added to settings.py above my current app). This works and migrations work however ./manage test still fails with the same issue that pgcrypto does not exist. Looks like it's not running my migration properly.. annoying as I'll have to figure out a way to defeat our build-scripts and inject something into 001_Initial manually

Comment: Make sure you have added your dummy app to `INSTALLED_APPS`, and added the dependency to migration `0001_initial` for any apps that use `EncryptedTextField`.

Comment: I have - it's been added to INSTALLED_APPS. I cannot add it as a dependency inside of my app's migrations as I mentioned our build-server keeps deleting the migration files in order to re-create on each run. Having said that, during testing it should still work since my dummy app appears above the current app in INSTALLED_APPS and I've confirmed its migrations are being executed in a normal run. Not sure what order ./manage.py test picks for its migrations but clearly isn'y working

Comment: Aha.. I see when I run a manual migration, it's running my dummy app's migrations *after* the app migrates, no wonder it fails. Without adding a dependency, how can I make it run the dummy app's migration earlier on? Shouldn't the order in which it appears in INSTALLED_APPS have helped?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't spotted your commend about the build script deleting the migration files. Can't you make it delete all migrations except `0001_initial`. I don't have any other suggestions apart from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help primarily from @Alasdair, I was able to setup a dummy app that sits between my app and the rest. I was then able to tweak my dependencies such that the build-server continues to clean up migrations in the real app, while always installing the pgcrypto extension before my app is migrated.